# Limiting access to one directory when on subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

Howdy, I need to do the following:

- allow access to sub.domain.com/directory *from* www.domain.com (linking to an asset)
- prevent access to sub.domain.com/* (Return a 404 page when user hits subdomain directly

Is this possible using htaccess and, if so, any pointers on how to accomplish it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess you might want to look up htaccess and regex tutorials as they are of great help.

Stop sites from hotlinking is what I assume you are referring to therefore: you need to enable mod_rewrite and add this to the .htaccess file in the domain's root directory (with a little of what you learn):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://www.domain.com/noHotlink.gif
```

This should point you in the right direction towards how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not really sure it's hotlinking that I'm trying to prevent. Let me elaborate - We have a subdomain that is mirroring the main site - we are serving assets/images from the subdomain - we need to be able to return a 404 whenever somebody hits the subdomain directly (any page), so...

if you hit www.domain.com, images on that page are served from images.domain.com.

if you hit images.domain.com, theoretically, since the subdomain is simply mirroring the www, you would be able to see the site - we need to prevent that from happening and simply return a 404.